# How to create the following symbol? Fractional function

Tags: graphics, symbols

How to create the following symbol?
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what does this notation mean? Is it equivalent to a regular fraction? So (x-x0)/rho(x0,x1)?

Comment: `$\varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \underline{x-x_0}\mkern-2mu\big/\mkern-2mu\overline{\rho(x_0,x_1)}$`

Comment: @HenriMenke, please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: The formatting directives `\mkern-2mu` and `\big/` appear to be OK for a font size of 10pt and Computer Modern math fonts, but they aren't quite as good for other font sizes and other math font families. A TikZ-based approach to draw the zig-zag line may be called for.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to just use two rules and connect them  with a slash kerned by a little negative space.  This does *not* scale with the content where a more sophisticated approach is needed, i.e. putting things in a box and measure the height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\fractional[2]{%
  \underline{#1}\mkern-2mu\raise .1ex \hbox{$\big/$}\mkern-1.5mu\overline{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\[ \varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \fractional{x-x_0}{\rho(x_0,x_1)} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is a variant that scales almost nicely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\fractional[2]{%
  \mathpalette\dofractional{{#1}{#2}}
}
\newcommand\dofractional[2]{%
  \dofractionalindeed#1#2
}
\newcommand\dofractionalindeed[3]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#2$}%
  \setbox1=\hbox{$#1#3$}%
  \ifdim\ht0>\ht1
    \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0+1pt
  \else
    \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht1+1pt
  \fi
  \ifdim\dp0>\dp1
    \dimen1=\dimexpr\dp0+1pt
  \else
    \dimen1=\dimexpr\dp1+1pt
  \fi
  \rlap{\vrule height -\dimen1 width \wd0 depth \dimexpr\dimen1+\fontdimen8\textfont3}
  \box0
  \mkern-2mu
  \mathord{\left/\vrule height \dimen0 depth \dimen1 width 0pt\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
  \mkern-2mu
  \rlap{\vrule height \dimexpr\dimen0+\fontdimen8\textfont3 width \wd1 depth -\dimen0}
  \box1
}
\begin{document}
\[ \varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \scriptscriptstyle \fractional{x-x_0}{\rho(x_0,x_1)} \]
\[ \varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \scriptstyle \fractional{x-x_0}{\rho(x_0,x_1)} \]
\[ \varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \fractional{x-x_0}{\rho(x_0,x_1)} \]
\[ \varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \textstyle \fractional{\int x-x_0}{\sum \rho(x_0,x_1)} \]
\[ \varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \fractional{\int x-x_0}{\sum \rho(x_0,x_1)} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer!  But allow me a few minor remarks:  1) You shouldn’t use `\box1` and `\dimen1` for local assignments.  2) I don’t understand the reason for the initial `\dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0 \dimen1=\dimexpr\ht1+\dp1`.  3) IMHO, a `\dimexpr` is best closed with `\relax` before an `\else` (at least), it’s too easy to overlook what comes after the conditional.  4) (Not sure about this one, needs experiments.)  You might also want to consider locally resetting `\delimiterfactor` and `\delimitershortfall` (see, _e.g._, the output of your fourth example; true that the available sizes are those…).

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti (1) Why shouldn't I use `\box1` and `\dimen1`?  From the TeXbook I know »Furthermore, plain TeX reserves `\dimen0` to `\dimen9`, `\skip0` to `\skip9`, `\muskip0` to `\muskip9`, and `\box0` to `\box9` for “scratchwork”; these registers are never allocated by the `\new...` operations. We have seen that `\count0` through `\count9` are special, and `\box255` also turns out to be special; so those registers should be avoided unless you know what you are doing.«

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti (2) These were just leftovers from a previous attempt I forgot to delete.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti (3) If you look carefully you will notice that every assignment and comparison of a register is followed by a space (newline counts as space).  When TeX is scanning for number it will stop as soon as a non-number character is encountered.  If you look in `plain.tex` you will find that all assignments are followed by a space rather than `\relax`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti (4) It already doesn't scale really well, so I don't care about this one but in principle you are right.

Comment: @HenriMenke If you do `\ifdim\ht0>\ht1 \dimen0=\dimexpr\ht0+1pt \else…` and the test returns true, then TeX will expand the `\else` before doing the assignment, because the `\dimexpr` has not yet ended. This will remove everything up to `\fi`, which will again be expanded; if something follows that can be interpreted as a number, you'd be in trouble. Add `\relax` as Gustavo suggested. About not using odd numbered registers for local assignments, look for “save stack buildup” in the index of the TeXbook and go to pages 301 and 346.

Comment: To Henri Menke: @egreg has already answered you; let me just add that, in your code, the `\ifdim\dp0>\dp1` conditional will be evaluated *before* the assignment to `\dimen0` gets executed.  Were you conscious of this?  I repeat, in this case this doesn’t hurt, but you will agree that it’s a bit of a luck, and that in other circumstances this could have been quite a mysterious bug… :-)  **Edit:** Note that a `\relax` after `\fi` suffices.

Answer (score 5):

The following solution draws the complete line with all three parts in *one* drawing operation. The advantages are

- proper line join,
- constant line width.

The drawing is done with TikZ (which would also allow to change the line styles, line joins, and line caps).

- The correct line width is extracted from the font dimen register:

  ```
  \fontdimen8\<text|script|scriptscript>font3
  ```
- The formula is separated from the line by a gap of three line widths
  in `\underline` and `\overline`. Also, TeXs sets an outer margin below/above the line with the amount of one line width.
- `\overline` uses a *cramped* math style for the formula. For example, superscripts are lowered a bit. LuaTeX has commands for setting the cramped math styles. Without LuaTeX, the solution uses macro `\cramped` of package `mathtools`.

Implementation with example and test cases:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \IfFileExists{luatex85.sty}{\usepackage{luatex85}}{}
  % LuaTeX provides \<mathstyle>cramped
\fi
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname crampedscriptstyle\endcsname\relax
  \usepackage{mathtools} % for \cramped
  \newcommand*{\SetCrampedStyle}[2]{%
    \cramped[#1]{#2}%
  }
\else
  \newcommand*{\SetCrampedStyle}[2]{%
    {%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle\crampeddisplaystyle
      \else\ifx#1\textstyle\crampedtextstyle
      \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\crampedscriptstyle
      \else\crampedscriptscriptstyle
      \fi\fi\fi
      #2%
    }%
  }
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fractional}[2]{%
  \mathpalette{\@fractional{#1}{#2}}{}%
}
\newcommand*{\fractionalAngle}{65}
\newcommand*{\@fractional}[4]{%
  % #1, #2: arguments of \fractional
  % #3: math style
  % #4: unused
  %
  % Get the line width for this math style
  \edef\@LineWidth{%
    \the\fontdimen8
    \ifx#3\displaystyle\textfont
    \else\ifx#3\textstyle\textfont
    \else\ifx#3\scriptstyle\scriptfont
    \else\scriptscriptfont
    \fi\fi\fi
    3%
  }
  %
  % Set the left and right part in boxes for measurment and usage.
  % Note the cramped style for the right part as in \overline and \sqrt.
  \sbox0{$#3#1\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#3\SetCrampedStyle{#3}{#2}\m@th$}%
  %
  % Calculate the total height for the slanted line
  \edef\@SlashTotalHeight{%
    \the\dimexpr
      \dp0 + \ht2
      + \@LineWidth * 7 % 2 * (3 [space] + 1/2 [line])
    \relax
  }%
  %
  % Calculate the width of the slanted line
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\@SlashWidth{%
    \@SlashTotalHeight * cos(\fractionalAngle)%
  }%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    inner sep=0pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
    baseline=(Left.base),
    line width=\@LineWidth,
  ]
    \draw[overlay] % Bounding box is set later
      % Left and right part are set as nodes
      node[anchor=base east] (Left) {\copy0}
      ++(\@SlashWidth, 0)
      node[anchor=base west] (Right) {\copy2}
      %
      % Line is drawn
      (Left.south west)
      ++(0, -3.5\pgflinewidth)
      -- ++(\wd0, 0)
      -- ++(\@SlashWidth, \@SlashTotalHeight)
      -- ++(\wd2, 0)
    ;%
    % Bounding box
    \useasboundingbox[outer sep=-.5\pgflinewidth]
      (Left.south west) ++(0, -5\pgflinewidth)
      (Right.north east) ++(0, 5\pgflinewidth)
    ;%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother


% Testing
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\Annot}[1]{\text{\scriptsize\quad(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\[ \varPhi^{n,n}(x) = f_0 + \fractional{x-x_0}{\rho(x_0,x_1)} \]
\[
  \underline{x_0}
  \begingroup\color{red}
    \fractional{\color{black}x_0}{\color{black}x^{\color{red}0}}
  \endgroup
  \overline{x^{\color{red}0}}
  \Annot{Positions}
\]
\[
  \def\test{
    {\color{blue}\fractional{\color{black}x_0}{\color{black}x^0}}
  }
  \test\,
  \scriptstyle\test\,
  \scriptscriptstyle\test
  \Annot{Line widths}
\]
\[
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{.2pt}
  \def\test#1{\textcolor{red}{\fbox{\color{black}$#1$}}}%
  \test{\underline{x_0}}\,
  \test{\fractional{x_0}{x^0}}\,
  \test{\overline{x^0}}
  \Annot{Bounding boxes}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]