# Two-headed version of \Rightarrow or \implies

Tags: arrows

I am looking for a variant of `\Rightarrow` with two arrowheads like [image: \RightArrow], call it `\RightArrow`. Need a similar symbol for `\LeftArrow` as well. Thanks in advance.

My first attempt is:

```
\def\RightArrow{\Rightarrow\makebox{\hspace*{-13pt}$\Rightarrow$}}
```

EDIT:

In the best case, I would like the new symbol `\RightArrow` to be as pretty and as well proportioned as `\Rightarrow`. If this is not feasible then I will settle for a solution that is better than my first attempt. Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would `TikZ` commands be acceptable for you?

Comment: I am working in math mode, I am also using `TikZ` for drawing pictures. If the `TikZ` solution works in math mode, then it must be ok.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/324471/34551 This question could expand that collection of arrows!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution based on Ti*k*Z, and inspired by the [solution of Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330051/15830). I have defined `\Implies` and `\Impliedby` for ease of use with correct spacing. This solution adapts to the smaller fonts used in super-/subscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\RightArrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette{\@RightArrow}{}}}
\newcommand*{\LeftArrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette{\@LeftArrow}{}}}

\newcommand*{\@RightArrow}[1]{%
    % Get the line width for this math style
    \edef\@LineWidth{%
        \the\fontdimen8
        \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
        \else\scriptscriptfont
        \fi\fi\fi
        3}
    \edef\@ScaleWidth{%
        \ifx#1\displaystyle0.39
        \else\ifx#1\textstyle0.39
        \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle0.35
        \else0.31
        \fi\fi\fi}
    \text{$\tikz
    \draw[double equal sign distance, line width=\@LineWidth,
    -{Implies[sep=-0.5ex] . Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale width=\@ScaleWidth, scale length=0.8]}]
    (0,0) -- (1.5em,0);$}}

\newcommand*{\@LeftArrow}[1]{%
    % Get the line width for this math style
    \edef\@LineWidth{%
        \the\fontdimen8
        \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
        \else\scriptscriptfont
        \fi\fi\fi
        3}
    \edef\@ScaleWidth{%
        \ifx#1\displaystyle0.39
        \else\ifx#1\textstyle0.39
        \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle0.35
        \else0.31
        \fi\fi\fi}
    \text{$\tikz
    \draw[double equal sign distance, line width=\@LineWidth,
    -{Implies[sep=-0.5ex] . Computer Modern Rightarrow[scale width=\@ScaleWidth, scale length=0.8]}]
    (1.5em,0) -- (0,0);$}}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\Implies}{\DOTSB\;\RightArrow\;}
\newcommand*{\Impliedby}{\DOTSB\;\LeftArrow\;}
\[
    a \implies b \qquad a \Implies b \qquad a \Impliedby b
\]
\[
    x^{a \implies b} \qquad x^{a \Implies b} \qquad x^{a \Impliedby b}
\]
\[
    x^{x^{a \implies b}} \qquad x^{x^{a \Implies b}} \qquad x^{x^{a \Impliedby b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

It should be possible to simplify this code, avoiding the redundant code, but I am not skilled enough with TeX programming to do so.

---

### Alternative solution

This solution uses equal arrowheads, as requested by the original poster.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\RightArrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette{\@RightArrow}{}}}
\newcommand*{\LeftArrow}{\mathrel{\mathpalette{\@LeftArrow}{}}}

\newcommand*{\@RightArrow}[1]{%
    % Get the line width for this math style
    \edef\@LineWidth{%
        \the\fontdimen8
        \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
        \else\scriptscriptfont
        \fi\fi\fi
        3}
    \text{$\tikz
    \draw[double equal sign distance, line width=\@LineWidth,
    -{Implies[sep=-0.35ex] . Implies}]
    (0,0) -- (1.5em,0);$}}

\newcommand*{\@LeftArrow}[1]{%
    % Get the line width for this math style
    \edef\@LineWidth{%
        \the\fontdimen8
        \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
        \else\ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont
        \else\scriptscriptfont
        \fi\fi\fi
        3}
    \text{$\tikz
    \draw[double equal sign distance, line width=\@LineWidth,
    -{Implies[sep=-0.35ex] . Implies}]
    (1.5em,0) -- (0,0);$}}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\Implies}{\DOTSB\;\RightArrow\;}
\newcommand*{\Impliedby}{\DOTSB\;\LeftArrow\;}
\[
    a \implies b \qquad a \Implies b \qquad a \Impliedby b
\]
\[
    x^{a \implies b} \qquad x^{a \Implies b} \qquad x^{a \Impliedby b}
\]
\[
    x^{x^{a \implies b}} \qquad x^{x^{a \Implies b}} \qquad x^{x^{a \Impliedby b}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of alternative solution]

Comment: In this solution, is it possible to make the outer arrow tip an exact replica of the inner arrow tip? so that the new symbol has the same look-and-feel as `\Rightarrow` or `\implies`. Thanks

Comment: @userOne: Yes, that is possible, but are you sure you want that? I think the spacing between the two arrowheads looks better if they are not exact replicas. I'll update the solution with your alternative.

Comment: I am going with this solution, works fine in the display-math mode, but there is an extra space when used in inline-math mode like ``$\RightArrow$``, whereas ``$\Rightarrow$`` does not have extra space. Can you help?

Comment: You're right, spacing was wrong in inline mode. I've moved the `\mathrel` command, which should improve the spacing.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two solutions, based partly or fully on glyphs in `mathabx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
matha7 <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9 <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{ <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8>
mathb7 <8-9> mathb8 <9-10> mathb9 <10-12> mathb10 <12-> mathba12 }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ggcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"CF}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gcurly}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"A1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varRightarrow}{\mathrel}{matha}{"F1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varRelbar}{\mathrel}{matha}{"F9}

\newcommand\RightArrow{\mathrel{\Relbar\mkern-10.5mu\raisebox{0.05ex}{\scalebox{0.9}{$ \ggcurly $}}}}
\newcommand\varRightArrow{\mathrel{\varRightarrow\mkern-11mu\raisebox{0.06ex}{\scalebox{0.8}[0.89]{$ \gcurly $}}}}

\newcommand\LongRightArrow{\mathrel{\Relbar\mkern-2.8mu\Relbar\mkern-10.5mu\raisebox{0.05ex}{\scalebox{0.9}{$ \ggcurly $}}}}
\newcommand\varLongRightArrow{\mathrel{\varRelbar\mkern-2.8mu\varRightarrow\mkern-11mu\raisebox{0.06ex}{\scalebox{0.8}[0.89]{$ \gcurly $}}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}%
A & \RightArrow B &\qquad A & \LongRightArrow B\\
 A & ⇒ B & A & \Longrightarrow B\\%
A & \varRightArrow B & A & \varLongRightArrow B\\
 \end{alignat*}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your solution, instead of using `\ggcurly` as the outer arrow tip, is it possible to make a copy of the inner arrow tip (one from `\implies` or `\Rightarrow`) and use that as the outer arrow tip? This will make the new symbol `\RightArrow` very much similar to `\Rightarrow` or `\implies` in its look-and-feel. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of any glyph which would be only the arrow tip. Maybe looking at the `metafont` code, and using `metapost` to change it to a  postscript file, some specialist could do that. But is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 3):

Overlapping arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\joinarrows}{\mathrel{\mspace{-14mu}}}

\newcommand{\Tworightarrow}{\Rightarrow\joinarrows\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\Twoleftarrow}{\Leftarrow\joinarrows\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\Twoleftrightarrow}{%
  \Leftarrow\joinarrows\Leftarrow
  \joinarrows
  \Rightarrow\joinarrows\Rightarrow
}
\newcommand{\Twolongrightarrow}{\Longrightarrow\joinarrows\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\Twolongleftarrow}{\Leftarrow\joinarrows\Longleftarrow}
\newcommand{\Twolongleftrightarrow}{%
  \Leftarrow\joinarrows\Longleftarrow
  \joinarrows
  \Rightarrow\joinarrows\Rightarrow
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Tworightarrow \quad \Twoleftarrow \quad \Twoleftrightarrow \\
\Twolongrightarrow \quad \Twolongleftarrow \quad \Twolongleftrightarrow
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to check if I understand it: The neg space is defined as relation because there is no space between relations, right?

Comment: In this solution, if the horizontal lines that appear between the two arrow tips can be erased then this will be the golden solution for my problem. See the image in the question. I used gimp to erase the lines between the arrow tips. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @userOne No, for that you need something like TikZ

Answer (score 2):

Will this do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\LeftArrow}{\ensuremath{\ll\!\!\!=\!\!=}}
\newcommand{\RightArrow}{\ensuremath{=\!\!=\!\!\!\gg }}
\begin{document}

\[ A\RightArrow B\]
\[ C\LeftArrow D\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is better than my first attempt, but there is a spacing issue between `=` and `\gg` or `\ll`. Is there a way to precisely fit these symbols together? Thanks.